# How to scroll a large image inside a smaller div using mouse click and drag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I want to place a large image inside a div and let the user scroll through the image using the mouse (click and drag to the desired direction). How can this effect be achieved?

CSS:

```
#image{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 300px;
    background: url("http://www.treasurebeachhotel.com/images/property_assets/treasure/page-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

EDIT:
I want to implement this myself in order to gain knowledge, 3rd party frameworks are last resort.

Comment: Just discovered this library. It is awesome and perfectly respond with phones : http://interactjs.io/ it might help you

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:200;height:200;overflow:scroll;">
            <img src="/home/james/Pictures/scone_ontology.png" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery UI Draggable.  The first example sounds like exactly what you are trying to do:
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score -1):

So you just want 600w 400h div, with a "map" inside that you can scroll around and look at with the mouse? You're very close already.

Have a div  with the size you want the end-product to take up. Make sure you set its css to  `overflow:scroll;`. Then put your image inside this div. Your image can ofcourse also be the background-image of a div.

And that's it.

A cool trick would be to wrapp all this up in a div that is slightly smaller, with `overflow:hidden`. Just small enough to hide ugly scrollbars. But that might be bad usability.

Comment: `overflow:scroll` looks like not working for images, i'm unable to scroll through the image.